# LNK1104 cannot open x.lib

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2013

I keep getting this error but the weird part is that the project comiles and runs fine. I can't see where the problem is, and i am sure it must find that library to work ok.

Comment: Is it actually called `x.lib` or that is just a dummy name?

Answer (score 0):

Probally there is an invalid reference for *x.lib* in your project configuration.
If it's compiling and working fine, maybe you have a valid **and** an invalid configuration for *x.lib*.

Comment: I am sorry. I was confused. it isn't compiling. 

This is the output:

    `1>  Shape.cpp
    1>  Circle.cpp
    2>  fabricadorFiguras.cpp
    1>  Converter.cpp
    1>  RegularPolygon.cpp
    2>  Engine.cpp
    1>  Rectangle.cpp
    2>  Generating Code...
    1>  Scenary.cpp
    2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'WormsModel.lib'
    1>  Generating Code...`       

All that have a 1> belongs to x.lib. It looks like it tryes to finish compiling the file that need that library(2>) before the library itself. Is there any way to set an order for the compilation?

Comment: Click right button in your project at "Solution Explorer" then select Properties->Linker->General check if all paths int "Additional Library Directories" are valids. Here you must to provide the valid path for 'WormsModel.lib'